# $http.jsonp - working on the browser but not on my phone

Tags: angularjs, rss, yeoman, ionic-framework

all i want is to build a simple RSS Application. the app so far working fine on the browser but when i try build this into my phone the whole rss part is disappear.
im using angular on the ionic-yeoman framework.

my service:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('RedColor.services', [])

.factory('myService', function($http) {
   return {
     getFoo: function() {
       // since $http.get returns a promise,
       // and promise.then() also returns a promise
       // that resolves to whatever value is returned in it's 
       // callback argument, we can return that.
       return $http.jsonp('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=50&callback=JSON_CALLBACK&q=http://www.ynet.co.il/Integration/StoryRss1854.xml');
     }
   }
});
```

my Controller:

```
.controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function(myService,$scope) {
       myService.getFoo().then(function(data) {
       // this will execute when the 
       // AJAX call completes.
       $scope.playlists = data.data.responseData.feed.entries;
       console.log(data);
   });
})
```

my HTML:

```
  <ion-content class="has-header">
    <ion-list>
        <h2 align="right">מבזקים</h2>
        <ul align="right">
            <li ng-repeat="playlist in playlists">{{playlist.title}}</li>
        </ul>
      <ion-item align="right" class="item-icon-right" ng-repeat="playlist in playlists track by $index" href="#/app/playlists/{{playlist.id}}">
        {{playlist.title}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting http before the Google api:

> > > return $http.jsonp('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load...');